# Which types of aircraft need a gust lock? Is there a size / performance influence?

Tags: aircraft-design

Which aircraft require gust locks on control surfaces?  Is there a certain range in the middle in terms of size / performance where gust locks (external / internal) are required?

From a cursory analysis is looks like the smaller / larger aircraft do not seem to have gust locks?Is there a certain tradeoff in size where they become required?

Does it depend on the type of actuators used for the control surfaces (e.g. hydraulic etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Hydraulically driven surfaces generally don't require gust locks because the damping action of the actuator(s) is sufficient.

Non-hydraulic surfaces, that can be freely be blown around by the wind, generally do (an exception is something like a manual rudder that is linked into a nosewheel steering mechanism that inhibits free movement of the rudder on the ground - you don't need a gust lock on that).

This is either a mechanical locking system incorporated into the control linkage (best option as long as the mechanism is designed to make it impossible to take off with the mechanism engaged), or external locks installed after flight (not optimal, because you depend on the flight crew to confirm they are removed, and people screw up), or barring that, the old seat belt around the control column trick you typically use on light aircraft without a dedicated gust lock.

Bottom line is, regardless of the size of airplane, if the surfaces can be blown around and bang on their limit stops on the ground, you have to do something, even if it's just a seatbelt around the stick.

Comment: This implies the highest risk is on the “fly-by-fly” systems where the control surfaces are free floating and you control servo tabs, because there the yoke still moves even if the gust lock is engaged.

Comment: The Britannia had hydraulically operated control locks but I'm not sure exactly how they worked.  On the Dehavilland Canada products, the lock is always designed with an operating lever that blocks throttle movement out of idle when engaged, precluding flight with them on, and I think most airplanes with remotely operated locks do something along those lines.